# Can you give an example of magnetic dipole transitions?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics, dipole, dipole-moment

There are electric dipole transitions some result in photon emission

The selection rules for magnetic transition are more or less same. What are examples of such transition and do they emit light ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the best-known magnetic dipole transition is between hydrogen atom 1s triplet and singlet states (wavelength 21 cm). (https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Sept04/Giovanelli/Giovanelli1_2.html)

EDIT: as for light emitted in magnetic dipole transitions, please see https://www.photonics.ethz.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/pdf/Papers/kasperczyk15a.pdf (PRL 114,163903 (2015))